# Laravel - How to get all columns if table is null or specific value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I get all data where "status" is "null" or "status" is "z" in one query?

Table columns: id, content, status

```
$pitanja = KartonPitanja::whereNull("pol")->where("pol","z")->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use orWhere like this

```
$pitanja = KartonPitanja::whereNull("pol")->orWhere("pol","z")->get();
```